# php regex issue

Tags: php, regex

I'm using a bit of code I found on the internet somewhere to compress my css files and it works great, however there is one regex issue that is causing a bit of trouble.

```
$css = preg_replace('/([\\w#\\.\\*]+)\\s+([\\w#\\.\\*]+){/', "$1\n$2{", $css);
```

This statement is supposed to separate multiple css rules on a single line into one css rule per line.

For example:

```
block_1 .block_2 {color:red} .block_3 .block_4 {color:blue}
```

Should become:

```
.block_1 .block_2 {color:red} 
.block_3 .block_4 {color:blue}
```

But what it does is something like:

```
.block_1 
.block_2 {color:red} .block_3 
.block_4 {color:blue}
```

It does the same thing with rules such as

```
.block_1 p {} div.x div {}
```

Can someone take a quick look at that regex line? Regex is NOT my forte :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's just me, but wouldn't a simple string replace work too?

Just replace `}` with `}\n` and you're done.

Comment: this is without a doubt one of those "I'm stupid" moments, this fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel with regex *(which is hard, and leads to regex no-one -- not even you -- will understand)*, you should **use an existing tool**, that's been tested a lot, and is already mature.

For example, you might want to take a look at the [**YUI Compressor's CSS minifier**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html)

Comment: problem is I don't really want to rely on external api's or have to install additional software for this specific component